# Why mget returns array of 2 with second element null for 1 key in async-redis in node

Tags: node.js, redis, null

Please refer below code:-

```
static async testcode() {
        let c = await redis.mset(['123','hello']);
        redis.expireKey('123',60);
        let d = await redis.mget(['123']);
        console.log(d); // d prints ['hello',null] , what is null here?? using async-redis module  of node
    }
```